# Unable to enemurate all disks error in terraform while creating vm vsphere

Tags: terraform, vsphere, hcl

I tried to create a new VM "TEST" in vsphere using terraform, while specifying the disk I got this error in terraform ***"Error: error powering on virtual machine: powerOn task for vm "/Datacenter/vm/Test" failed: Unable to enumerate all disks."***  (Line where disk is specified)
and in Vsphere  ***"Unable to enumerate all disks. The file specified is not a virtual disk"***

Here is my Code:

```
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = "User"
  password       = "pass"
  vsphere_server = "IP"
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = "Datacenter"
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = "Datastore_name"
datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"  
}


data "vsphere_resource_pool" "pool" {
    name = "Resources"
datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

data "vsphere_network" "mgmt_lan" {
  name          = "Network"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}


resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "Test" {
  name             = "Test"
  resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id}"
  datastore_id = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"
  num_cpus         = 4
  memory           = 4096

  disk {
    label            = "disk0.vmdk"
    size             = 20
    thin_provisioned = true
  }

  network_interface {
   network_id     = "${data.vsphere_network.mgmt_lan.id}"
   adapter_type   = "vmxnet3"
  }

}
```

P.S: I changes names and passwords for privacy

Thank you in advance

Comment: getting same error? did you found a solution?